# Measurability of set in space of continuous functions (path space)

Tags: measure-theory, probability-theory, stochastic-processes

Consider $\left(C(\left[0,\infty\right)),\mathcal{C}_{\left[0,\infty\right)}\right)$
 , the space of continuous functions on $\left[0,\infty\right)$ with the canonical $\sigma$-alg $\mathcal{C}_{\left[0,\infty\right)}$, i.e. the smallest that makes the projections $\pi_{t}:C(\left[0,\infty\right))\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$ measurable.

I'd like to show that $E:=\left\{ x\in C(\left[0,\infty\right)):\exists t\geq0\;\mbox{s.t.}\; x_{t}=0\right\}$ is measurable, but I'm unsure how to proceed.

If we write $E=\bigcup_{t\geq0}\left\{ x\in C([0,\infty):x_{t}=0\right\}$, then each of the sets is measurable, but the uncountability of the union is problematic. The "usual" trick of only considering rationals doesn't seem to apply either.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Hint:** By the intermediate value theorem, there exists $t \in [0,R]$ such that $x_t=0$ if, and only if, one of the following statements holds true:

- $x(0)=0$
- $x(R)=0$
- $\forall k \in \mathbb{N} \, \exists r_1,r_2 \in \mathbb{Q} \cap (0,R): x(r_1)-\frac{1}{k}<0, x(r_2)+\frac{1}{k}>0.$

Conclude that

$$E_R := \{x \in C([0,\infty)); \exists t \in [0,R]: x_t=0\}$$

is measurable for all $R>0$. Then $$E = \bigcup_{N \in \mathbb{N}} E_N$$ is measurable as countable union of mesurable sets.

Comment: The "only if" follows from $x(t)−1/n<0$ and $x(t)+1/n>0$ by the density of $\mathbb{Q}$ and continuity. Could you give a hint on the "if" part? It's clear that we get the function converging to $0$, but I'm struggling to prove that there is a point where it assumes this value $0$.

Comment: I'm thinking in the lines of: If $x(r_{1})>0>x(r_{2})$ for one of the pairs $r_{1},r_{2}$ then the result follow from the Intermediate Value Theorem. If they're both always positive (or always negative), then the result follows from the fact that the function converges to $0$ and must obtain its minimum (or maximum).

Comment: But my "proof" would require us to consider the closed interval. An in fact, I think this is necessary: If $x(t):=t/2$, then $x(1/k)=1/(2k)<1/k$. Hence it satisfies the statement on $(0,1)$, but $x(0)=0$ is the only place it's zero, so there is no $t$ in $(0,1)$ where it's zero.

Comment: @ProbStudent Yeah, you are right, we need the interval. Should be fine now.

Comment: Many thanks for help!